# How do I view data during debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ienumerable

I always get the remark "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable" while debugging and trying to view what's in my local array.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 for Web and coding in C#.
How do I view my data?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/expanding-the-results-view-will-enumerate-the-ienumerable-us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerable's in C# are subject to [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669162.aspx), and so if you have an Enumerable object which has only been assigned to but not yet used then you will encounter the "Expanding results view" message when debugging.

Here is a simple example of this to help illustrate

```
string[] myArr = { "one", "two", "" };
var query = myArr.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
foreach(var q in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(q);
}
```

In this example, setting a breakpoint on the foreach and inspecting the value of `query` in the debugger will give you the message you are referring to - this is because the execution of the `.Where` has been deferred until the collection is actually enumerated.
Luckily for us that will happen in the next line, since the foreach will iterate over the collection causing the `.Where` to execute.

However you may find there will be situations where the collection isn't enumerated until much later - I believe this to be one of the benefits of deferred execution, as it allows for perceived performance at runtime (especially over a large collection).
A brief example could be that a user may access a page in your application which amongst other things has a rarely used drop down list containing a large collection of objects. Rather than have the drop down list slow down the loading of that page by enumerating the large collection of objects, it is instead better to defer that enumeration until after the page has loaded and the user decides to use drop down list to view the collection (which they may never do!).

However, you can force the execution to occur immediately rather than waiting for the array to be enumerated in which you simply call `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` on the query like so

```
var query = myArr.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Now when you are debugging you will see the contents of query populated before it is used in the foreach.